# Global static variable not "staying defined" outside of function

Tags: c++

I have a program in which a static variable I defined globally will not remain initialized once it leaves my "initialization function" (not a constructor). Here is that program:

**type.h**

```
namespace type
{
    static int * specialInt;
}
```

**type.cpp**

```
#include "type.h"
```

(this is intentionally left empty)

**Branch.h**

```
#include "type.h"

namespace type
{
    bool initInt();
}
```

**Branch.cpp**

```
#include "Branch.h"
#include <iostream>

namespace type
{
    bool initInt()
    {
        specialInt = new int;
        *specialInt = 95;
        std::cout << "Address from initInt(): " << specialInt << std::endl;
        return true;
    }
}
```

**Leaf.h**

```
#include "Branch.h"
#include <iostream>

namespace type
{
    void PrintInt();
}
```

**Leaf.cpp**

```
#include "Leaf.h"

namespace type
{
    void PrintInt()
    {
        std::cout << "Address: " << specialInt << std::endl;
        std::cout << "Value:   " << *specialInt << std::endl;
    }
}
```

**main.cpp**

```
#include "Leaf.h"

int main()
{
    type::initInt();
    type::PrintInt();
    return 0;
}
```

The output is

> Address from initInt(): 007F5910
>
> Address: 00000000

before it crashes. I read that the keyword `static` lets variables have external linkage, so why is this failing? Why does the variable become undefined outside of `initInt()`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
namespace type
{
    static int * specialInt;
}
```

This is a *definition* of a static integer pointer. `static` at namespace scope requests internal linkage: every translation unit which includes `type.h` gets its own, independent version of `specialInt`. Then, of course, changes made to one of the `specialInt`s do not affect the other ones.

What you wan to do is *declare* the variable in `type.h`:

```
namespace type
{
    extern int * specialInt;
}
```

... and provide a single definition in one of the translation units:

```
#include "type.h"

int *type::specialInt;
```

This definition will then be found and used by everyone via `type.h`.

Answer (score 1):

> I read that the keyword `static` lets variables have external linkage,

No, when [static](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/storage_duration#Explanation) is used with object at namespace scope, it specifies internal linkage. That means, the `specialInt` assigned in `Branch.cpp`, and the `specialInt` printed in `Leaf.cpp`, are not the same object.

> 3) ... When used in a declaration at namespace scope, it specifies
>   internal linkage.